# Number Systems-Hex vs Binary

Tags: binary, hex

Question with regards to the use of hexadecimal. Here's a statement I have a question about:

Hexadecimal is often the preferred means of representing data because it uses fewer digits than binary.
For example, the word *vim* can be represented by:

- Hexadecimal: 76 69 6D
- Decimal: 118 105 109
- Binary: 01110110  01101001
  01101101

Obviously, hex is shorter than binary in this example, however, wont the hex values eventually be converted to binary at the machine level so the end result for hex-binary is exactly the same?

Answer (score 1):

This is a good question.
Yes, the hexadecimal values will be converted in binaries at machine level.
But you are looking the question from the machine point of view.
Hexadecimal notation was introduced because:

1. It's more easy to read and memorize than binaries for human. For example if you are reading memory addresses, you can observe that they are actually written in hexadecimal, that is far more simple to read then binary.
2. It's easy to do calculation from binaries to hexadecimal than other base (like 
   our today-used base 10). For example, it's easy to group binary digits into hex in your head (4 bits per hex digit).

I suggest you [this](http://digiassn.blogspot.it/2006/02/why-do-we-use-hexadecimal.html) article that gives some easy example calculations to better understand hexadecimal advantages.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the info and the link.